# Expo & React Native: how to read assets in a directory and its subfolders (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Struggling to get audio files from a directory and its subdirectories using Expo libraries.
There's a `FileSystem` library where you can request a directory access and then read folder contents. It doesn't allow to read subdirectory files, you have to ask for access for every directory you want to get information from. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemreaddirectoryasyncfileuri

There's also `MediaLibrary` where you can get Assets passing `audio` as asset type, though you cannot provide a directory for that function, it gets all audio files on a device. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemreaddirectoryasyncfileuri

Is there a better method to get audio files in a folder for Android?

Tried methods: FileSystem: StorageAccessFramework, MediaLibrary: getAssetsAsync